# Access/Manipulate Points on NVD3 Line Chart

Tags: javascript, d3.js, nvd3.js

I want to access the points of an NVD3 line chart independently, so I may hide/show them selectively, and pass them metadata to display in their tooltips.

I have a chart with an X-axis showing hours, 0-24. I wish to be able to selectively hide/show point markers at only select hours, to indicate some type of event has occurred at that time.

I am looking for a way, preferably, to get all the points as an array, iterate through them, determine if they should be hidden or shown, and manipulate their colour, and metadata for their tooltip.

I don't see any examples of being able to select all the points, but I know there must be a way.

Thanks for your help!

Comment: Can you code up an example plunker or jsfiddle?  I'm curious what you consider a point?  Do you have a line chart with circles?  Or just a line?  When hide a "marker" does it just turn off a circle or adjust the line?

Comment: Sounds like that would be easier with plain D3. NVD3 doesn't really offer APIs for that kind of thing.

Comment: Yes, by "point" I'm referring to a circle, which usually only appears when mousing over an area of the line. I wish to be able to have the circles visible selectively, without having to mouse over them. Also, it is possible to use straight D3 from within NVD3, so that shouldn't be a problem.